# Chrome Extension that copies image URL on click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm brand new to making Chrome Extensions and have done the simple tutorials, but I'm having trouble finding what I need. I want the extension to allow a user to chose an image on a webpage, and then copy the URL for that image into the extension. Can anyone help me out? I'm sure if I see an example I'd get a better grasp on how extensions can interact with a page.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "copy that URL... *into the extension*"?  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I meant that when I click on any image, the src attribute of the <img> tag would be accessible to the Chrome extension so I could do things with it.

Comment: Added an alternative that might be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, I'd say you want to create a [context menu](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html) item that shows up when you right-click an image.  For example, in your background script, use:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Use URL of image somehow",
    contexts:["image"],
    onclick: function(info) {
        handleImageURL(info.srcUrl);
    }
});

function handleImageURL(url) {
    // now do something with the URL string in the background page
}
```

This will add a context menu item that shows up on all pages, but only when you right-click on images.  When the user selects it, the `onclick` handler of the menu item fires `handleImageURL` with the URL of the image as the argument.  The URL can be processed in any way you like, e.g., saved in a `localStorage` list, sent to a server via Ajax, or [passed in a message](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to a listening [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) in the current tab.

**EDIT with alternative:**

You might want a [content script](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) that gets injected into every page.  The script could bind an event listener to every image element at load time:

```
// in my_content_script.js...
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i = 0, i < imgs.length; ++i) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(this.src);
        // do things with the image URL, this.src
    });
}
```

To inject it into all subdomains of `example.com`, your manifest would include:

```
...
"content_scripts": {
    "matches":["*://*.example.com/*"],
    "scripts":["my_content_script.js"]
},
...
```

Note that this pure-JS solution doesn't attach listeners to images dynamically added after load time.  To do that in your content script with jQuery, use:

```
$(document).on("click", " img", function() {
    alert(this.src);
});
```

And add your jQuery file name to the `scripts` array in your manifest, next to `my_content_script.js`.

Comment: Thanks! So I know from the docs that "matches" is required. How do you write the matching so it works on any domain? Something like "http://*/*"?

Comment: That will work for HTTP pages but not HTTPS pages. The universal match pattern is `*://*/*` -- all files on all hosts over all domains. (Really just `http`, `https`, and `file`, if file access is permitted; any other protocol, such as `ftp`, is never allowed.)  See [Match Patterns](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) in the extension docs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [Google Chrome Extension sample](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#9e4fd06300ee2b3a171e1f30d1b70f8f10152c2b):

```
var images = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));
var imageURLs = images.map(function(image) {
  return image.src;
});
chrome.extension.sendRequest(images);
```

For a more detailed example (e.g. how to handle the request), you can check out this extension I wrote called [Image Downloader](https://github.com/vdsabev/image-downloader)