# chrome extension to copy image or link target url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a Chrome extension which would get a URL from image or link right clicked by user and passing this URL to Google search, all from within the context menu.

I have it **working perfectly on Firefox XPI**:

```
var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var searchMenu = cm.Item({
  label: "defi!",
  data: "https://www.google.co.il/search?hl=iw&gl=il&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=",
  context: cm.SelectorContext("a[href]"),
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                 '  var searchURL = data + node.href;' +
                 '  window.location.href = searchURL;' +
                 '});',
  items: [searchMenu]
});
```

I want the same thing to happen on a Chrome context-menu Extension. almost similar to this question:

[Chrome Extension that copies image URL on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423670/chrome-extension-that-copies-image-url-on-click)

I had this script working just before posting a question but always got `undefined` for `srcUrl`:

**Damn.js**

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Blah", 
  contexts:["image", "link"], 
  onclick:function(info){
    handleImageURL(info.srcUrl);
  }
});                         
function handleImageURL(info) {   
  var data = "https://www.google.co.il/search?hl=iw&gl=il&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=";
  var searchURL = data + [info.srcUrl];
  chrome.tabs.create({url: searchURL});
}
```

and **Manifest.json**

```
{ 
  "name": "blah",
  "description": "blah",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions":["tabs", "contextMenus"],
  "background": {"scripts":["damn.js"]},
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

But it's not working now at all.. not sure why..

**Edited** script above working all the way to google search but don't fetch image or link url

Comment: Can you be more precise? Is it not working for images, links, or both?

Comment: Both not working, when I click my context-menu item I'm getting to google search as supposed but the search query is "undefined", for example- www.google.com/q=Undefined.. main goal is to fetch the target URL behind the image or link and fetch it as a query to google search

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the onclick part. This works:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Blah", 
  contexts:["image", "link"], 
  onclick:handleImageURL
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to return the data info.srcURL from the onClick function

Comment: Mind giving a simple example how to get it done? I used this function at "function handleImageURL(info)" or should I call a new onClick function? thx..